# How Do I Search And Select First Option From website in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code which goes to https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/ , searches query and selects first element and downloads the rom, but its always selecting the same element despite of different query, I first thought website was giving same top result, but I checked with my browser but its giving different results, How can I fix / do this?

My Code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import asyncio

GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = 'path here'
CHROME_DRIVER = 'driver path here'

async def bruh(query="Redmi Note 8 Pro China"):
    url = "https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui"
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    w = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    search_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/section/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/label/input'
    next_page_url_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/section/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/a'
    version_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]/h5'
    name_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[8]/h5/span'
    w.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, search_xpath)))
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_xpath)
    elem.send_keys(query)
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    next_page_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_page_url_xpath)
    nextm = next_page_elem.get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(nextm)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    version_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(version_xpath).text
    name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(name_xpath).text
    version_elem = version_elem.replace("Version: ", "")
    print(version_elem)
    print(name_elem)
    url = f"https://bigota.d.miui.com/{version_elem}/{name_elem}"
    print(url)
    driver.close()
```

I want to visit website, send my query and select first option and convert it to download able url. can anyone help? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of extra stuff that I don't quite follow.

A few pieces of feedback...

1. Waiting for presence just means that the element is in the DOM, not that it's visible or interactable. If you are going to use click or send keys, you need to wait until clickable or visible, respectively, or you may get an exception.
2. You don't need all those sleeps, especially when you are using WebDriverWait. Best practice is to avoid sleeps (they make your script slower and less reliable), instead use WebDriverWait.
3. The wait for an element will return that element so you don't need to wait, then find, then click... you can just `wait.until(...).click()`.
4. You were getting the href from a link and then navigating to it... just click the link.
5. Instead of `replace()`, I just used `split()`... either is fine. I think `split()` is less likely to break, e.g. if they change the labels.

Updating your code based on my feedback above, this should work.

```
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input"))).send_keys(query)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#miui td > a"))).click()
version = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h5[./b[text()='Version: ']]"))).text.split()[1]
package_name = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "filename"))).text
print(version)
print(package_name)
url = f"https://bigota.d.miui.com/{version}/{package_name}"
print(url)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Getting This Error:

`
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
`

Comment: I don't know what line is causing the error given what you've posted. I don't have the ability to test this code in python.

Comment: Just to be clear... I wrote all of this in C# because I don't have a working python env. I tested all of the code and then converted it to python. It should work just fine because it's pretty simple/standard Selenium code.